# Prestashop price change during order process

Tags: php, prestashop

Is there possible to change price during order process in prestashop ?
I need to make module that would add shipping price depending on some conditions (can't do it in presta, need module).
I've tried to do it on some hooks (hookBackBeforePayment, hookBeforeCarrier, hookProcessCarrier, hookExtraCarrier) , i simply tried to change ['total_price'] or other variables that are passed to hook functions.

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something a carrier module should handle. Unfortunately, there's not much documentation regarding this topic, so it requires quite a bit of trial and error. There's a brief carrier module tutorial for PS 1.4 [here](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS14/Carrier+modules+-+functions,+creation+and+configuration) that might get you started. I would also suggest that you read the source code of other free shipping modules that exists.

Answer (score 0):

The getFields() function in Order.php carries all the data for placing an order.
By modifying this array you can be able to provide a custom price for the order.

```
public function getFields()
{
    if (!$this->id_lang)
        $this->id_lang = Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT', null, null, $this->id_shop);
    $val = parent::getFields();
    $val['total_paid'] = 5678.88;
    $val['total_paid_tax_incl'] = 5678.88;
    $val['total_paid_tax_excl'] = 5678.88;
    $val['total_paid_real'] = 0;
    $val['total_products'] = 5678.88;
    $val['total_products_wt'] = 5678.88;

    return $val; //Return this array
    //return parent::getFields();
}
```

Indeed you can place this function in override to make your prestashop upgradable. Ver: 1.5.5.0